# Unity2D ScrollView UI doesnt display its content in Android build

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

well as i said in the title, i have a ScrollView that has inside a Viewport and Content, i added clones of a SlotTemplate to the Content gridLayoutGroup by scripting:

```
private void loadContent()
    {
        List<Article> group = articles.ArticlesInGroup(groupId);

        for (int i = 0; i < group.Count; i++)
        {
            Transform addSlot = Instantiate(slotTemplate,content.transform);
            addSlot.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);

            addSlot.Find("ArticleImage").GetComponent<Image>().sprite=group[i].Sprite;
            addSlot.Find("ArticlePrice").GetComponent<Text>().text = group[i].Price.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that the ScrollView display its content correctly just in the Scene and Game view of Unity but when i build a apk for Android, it shows nothing, the scrollview appears but its content is empty.

-Details-

Content gameObject has rect Transform, gridLayoutGroup and content size fitter

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

After several testings i noticed that the problem was the json library, in android doesnt work, sorry for this post.